# Is it possible to cast a String to an int in the Spring xml-config

Tags: spring

Say I have a properties file 'config.properties' that contains this line:

```
myIntValue=4711
```

and a little java bean:

```
public MyLittleJavaBean {
    private int theInt;
    public void setTheInt(int theInt) { this.theInt = theInt }
}
```

In my applicationContext.xml I read the properties file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="config.properties"/>
```

and then I want to wire the stuff together like this:

```
<bean id="theJavaBean" class="MyLittleJavaBean">
    <property name="theInt" value="${myIntValue}"/>
</bean>
```

Then I'll get this errorMessage:

```
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property
value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'theInt'
```

Is it possible to cast ${myIntValue} to an int in the spring-xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm... there must be something funny with your setup, because for me spring does the String-to-Int convertion without any effort from my side. Here is a example which works for me:

**xml configuration**:

```
<util:properties id="props">
    <prop key="foobar">23</prop>
</util:properties>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="props" />
<bean class="Foo" p:bar="${foobar}" />
```

**Foo.java**

```
public class Foo {
    private int bar;

    public void setBar(int bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

tested with spring `3.1.2`

Comment: Yep, examining the property-file more closely, there was some garbage characters next to the int-value.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes is that exception unclear, but logic for compiler.

On my case was a wrong ref of value with ***$(name.itsn)*** that gives me that Exception.

Right way is **${name.itsn}**

check it out!
greetings 
sail